# Ember hasMany relationship temporarily created but not saving but belongsTo saves

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Hey everyone thanks for checking this out. I am new to Ember and am having an issue with my signup and the hasMany relationship not saving.

I have a Scout model that I have created as a fixture that has not yet been assigned to a userAccount.

```
App.Scout = DS.Model.extend(
  product:      DS.attr('string')
  condition:    DS.attr('string')
  price:        DS.attr('number')
  userAccount:  DS.belongsTo('userAccount')
)

App.Scout.FIXTURES = [
 {
  id:         1
  product:    'Clothing Hamper'
  condition:  'Not Smelly'
  price:      25
 }
]

App.UserAccount = DS.Model.extend
  email:    DS.attr('string')
  password: DS.attr('string')
  scouts:   DS.hasMany('scout')
```

I then go to the path of the scout that is created and signup the user and attempt to create the relationship between the user and the scout. After the user is signed up it goes to a switchboard, which checks App.currentUser.get('scouts.length') and reroutes it to the scout path if that == 1.

```
App.Router.map ->
  this.resource 'switchboard'
  this.resource 'scout', { path: '/scouts/:scout_id' }

App.ScoutRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    @store.find 'scout', params.scout_id
  afterModel: ->
    console.log("after transition currentUser's scout length: {App.currentUser.get('scouts.length')}") unless App.currentUser is null
  actions:
    createAccount: ->
      @currentModel.set('userAccount', App.currentUser)
      App.currentUser.get('scouts').pushObject(@currentModel)
      App.currentUser.save()

App.SwitchboardRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  beforeModel: ->
    console.log("before transition currentUser's scout length: {App.currentUser.get('scouts.length')}")
    if App.currentUser.get('scouts.length') == 1
      @transitionTo('scout', App.currentUser.get('scouts.firstObject').id)

App.ScoutController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  foo: App.get('currentUser.scouts.length')

App.UsersNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(
  identification: null
  password:       null
  actions:
    createAccount: ->
      user  = @store.createRecord('userAccount',
            email:    @get('identification')
            password: @get('password')
          )
      user.save()

      @transitionToRoute('switchboard')

      App.currentUser = user

      true
)
```

So that does equal one for the reroute but after the reroute is complete, when I type it in the console App.currentUser.get('scouts.length) or look in the ember inspector data the user does not have the scout attached to it. Also the userAccount is still attached to the Scout its just like its not saving it the other way around.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I also created a jsbin to look at it, http://jsbin.com/ENAWotu/17/edit

Thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar with the js notation that you are using, but it seems to me that you have to push the "scout" model when you create a new user. So before you do user.save(), you might want add equivalent of user.get("scouts").pushObject(SCOUT MODEL)

Comment: Its in coffeescript, and my thought is that I want the the UserNewController just to handle the signup, because people can signup without adding a scout. So thats why I tried to create the bubbling that will go from the UsersNewController eventually to the Scout Route. And just not getting why the connection is being created and works when it goes to the switchboard but then when its done transitioning the connection is lost.

Comment: Does this help? Adding a line in scouteRoute->createAccount action   
      App.currentUser.get("scouts").pushObject(@currentModel) immediately after @currentModel.set('userAccount', App.currentUser)

Comment: Good thought, but that doesn't change anything and everything still behaves the same. I am going to edit the example to include that. I am thinking maybe it has something to do with the fixture adapter but really quite confused on this one right now.

Comment: Where do you set `@currentModel` in your App.Scout route